# SQL injection test - mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection

I'm creating a test project for my classmates to show how php code with unchecked variables is dangerous.
I'm using the deprecated `mysql_*` function and a simple database with 2 tables:

```
users  
data
```

and in the users I have just the admin user.

I have created a simple html form:

```
    <form action="login" method="POST">
    username: <input type="text" name="username">
    password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
```

and the login.php page simply get the post data and build the query like this:

```
$uname = strtolower(trim($_POST['username']));
    $passw = strtolower(trim($_POST['password']));

$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE username='".$uname."' and password=MD5('".$passw."')"
    );
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 1){
        echo "Non valid";
    }else{
        echo "Logged in";
    }
```

and this is my input on username field:

```
&#39; or 1=1 --&#32;
```

that should produced a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' or 1=1 -- ' and password=MD5('')
```

if I run this query on SequelPro or PhpMyAdmin the query give me the first row of the table so it works.
But if I submit the form the result is `Not valid`.

I tried also to use the password field with this input:

```
&#39;) or 1=1 --&#32;
```

and this is the query generated:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' and password=MD5('') or 1=1 -- ')
```

but the result is the same, it works on SequelPro but not in the form.

I think that the mysql_query function will not recognize the `--` comment. Am I right?
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the exact error you are receiving from executing the query via `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @Christian: can you check the number of rows in table `users`. If there is more than one, see my answer below - otherwise I've to resign ;)

Comment: Ciao Christian, did you tried to limit 1 your query? Are you sure that your code will return only a row?

Comment: @Your Common Sense, your comment is unuseful, I'm studing this stuff, it's my first approach and my teacher asked me to prepare a demo to understand if I'm able to study something that he doesn teach already, so please any help is appreciate, no sarcasm

Comment: I wouldn call it sarcasm but rather bitterness. If he didn't teach you debugging, he isn't a teacher at all, but rather commonplace cargo cult preacher. If he did - you have to study what you have taught first.

Comment: By the way, your concept is wrong. It is not "unchecked data" but *improperly formatted query* being *the only* cause.

Comment: Can you give me any resources about debugging?

Answer (score 1):

try this in username field :

```
' or 1=1 or '
```

and enter password whatever you want.
don't forget about space after `'` s.
it turns your code like that:

```
mysql_query("select * from users where username='' or 1=1 or '' and 
password=".md5('$pass'))
```

and it always returns true.

it MUST work, if it doesnt, 
do this :

```
echo "
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE username='".$uname."' and password=MD5('".$passw."')";
```

and post the result as comment for me , maybe I could help you

Comment: Same result as my tests, the query works in SequelPro but not in mysql_query. I have used `&#39; or 1=1 or &#39;&#32;` as username and `hello` as password and the echo returns: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='' or 1=1 or ' ' and password=MD5('hello')`

Comment: oh, you should put MD5() in the `''` , try this and let me know what happened